# CSS Select sibling of element with child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Assume we have the following DOM structure and we'd like the `Hello world!` text to be red if the input element is focused:

```html
<input>
<label>Hello world!</label>
```

This could easily be achieved using the following css snippet:

```css
input:focus ~ label{
  color: red;
}
```

Now if we have this HTML structure:

```html
<div>
  <input>
</div>
<label>Hello world!</label>
```

Same problem: We'd like the label's text to be colored red if the input element inside the div is focused.

But for the life of me I can't figure out the correct CSS combinators.

I tried

```css
div input:focus ~ label{
  color: red;
}
```

but this only applies to `label`s that are siblings of the input and are embedded in the same `div` like so

```
<div>
  <input>
  <label>Hello world!</label>
</div>
```

which is not what I want.

It wouldn't be as much of a problem if there was a way of declaring precedence of CSS combinators:

```css
(div input:focus) ~ label{
  color: red;
}
```

sadly CSS doesn't seem to work like this :|

**My question:**

Given this HTML code:

```html
<div>
  <input>
</div>
<label>Hello world!</label>
```

**What would the CSS look like that colors the font of the label red iff the input element is focused (i.e. has the `:focus` pseudo class applied)?**

I know this could probably be hacked together with a couple lines of javascript but I'm curious if this is possible with pure HTML and CSS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46406959/8620333